# Add a new field from an object nested inside an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native, aggregates

I have two collections:

#### Assets collection:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "620bc49c937d954ed4acf813" },
  "opID": { "$oid": "620bc497937d954ed4acf810" },
  "issues": [{
    "otherFields": {...}
   }],
  "__v": 7
}
```

#### Operations collection:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "620bc49c937d954ed4acf813" },
  "name": "Test",
  "otherFields": [...],
  "__v": 7
}
```

I want to add the **operation name and _id** to all the **issue Objects** inside the Assets issue field.
My actual pipeline to do it is:

##### $lookup

```
{
          from: "operations",
          localField: "opID",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "operationsJoin",
        }
```

##### $unwind

```
{ path: "$issues" }
```

##### $addFields

```
"issues.operationId": "$operationsJoin._id"
```

##### $group

```
{
  _id: "$_id",
  issues: {
    $push: {issues:"$issues"}
  }
}
```

My first issue is at the $addFields stage. The operationsJoin field is an array and when the operationId field it's setted on the issue object it's created as an array as this:

```
issues: {
  operationId: [
    "5f3b8ff2906e402014832d33"
  ]
}
```

instead of:

```
issues: {
  operationId: "5f3b8ff2906e402014832d33"
  
}
```

and i cannot do:

```
"issues.operationId": "$operationsJoin[0]._id"
```

And the second issue it's that a doesn't know to add other field to the $group stage apart the issues array that i'm creating.

Anyone has an idea ?? Thanks for the help in advance

**Edited**:
I let an example of the pipeline here, for now i only want  the operationName and operationId fields to be strings, not arrays:
[Example Pipeline](https://mongoplayground.net/p/igSCqKEPcYO)

Comment: you cant use this kind of paths in aggregation, but you can do [this](https://cmql.org/play/?q=1646220189169) If you are still stuck, if you can give the expected output in json so we know what you need.

Comment: @Takis _ I let an example of the pipeline here, for now i only want  the operationName and operationId fields to be strings, not arrays:
[Example Pipeline](https://mongoplayground.net/p/igSCqKEPcYO)

Comment: I'm not sure of your intentions, but could this [mongoplayground.net aggregation pipeline](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MUchBSbhCzk "Click me!") be close to what you're looking for?